# Ask Spark to deactivate full sentence evaluation inside a an sql when/otherwise clause

Tags: apache-spark

I dont know if what I am asking for is possible but I need to find a solution.

I have a dataframe and I would like to add a column with a when otherwise clause:

```scala
val delta = df
  .withColumn("PC", when(col("PartitionKey")=!="[]", lit(spark.sql(s"SHOW Partitions $TableName").count())).otherwise(null))
```

Problem is spark is evaluation both parts of the sentence in all cases ans so when `PK=="[]"` it fails with `AnalysisException: SHOW PARTITIONS is not allowed on a table that is not partitioned` error which is normal.

I can think of two possible solutions :

1. Insert some sort of a try except code inside the when clause ==> Seems not possible at least if I don't take the whole if bloc out as a variable and than call it simply.
2. Order Spark not to evaluate the whole when otherwise ==> I dont know if it is possible.

Comment: Can you maybe explain on a high level what you want to do? Do you want to have a column that shows the number of partitions in a table if some column is not equal to `"[]"`? So that means that this column always has the same value and is otherwise `null`?

Comment: @Koedlt basically if the other column 'PartitionKey' is [] nothing need to be done and my column should be null.
Now if 'PartitionKey' isnt [] I need to execute an other sql instruction (show partitions) and write the number of partitions found in my column.
Actually if 'PartitionKey' is [] that means that my table have no partitions keys and so SHOW PARTITIONS returns an AnalysisException

Comment: Hmm can you maybe edit your question and add an example table of what your input looks like and the output is you're expecting? That will probably make this more clear